# Removing time format in a date

Tags: c#-4.0

I am passing a date as a parameter where daydate is the parameter

```
string daydate
```

The content of daydate is `3/3/2017 12:00:00 AM`

I am doing this to remove the time and still the time does not go away

```
string strCleanDate = String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", daydate);
```

How can I remove the time?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx Read this dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the formatter is ignored as the instance you are passing to `string.Format` is a string so the placeholder is filled with the value you passed in and the format is ignored completely. If you want to apply `DateTime` formatting you need to pass in an instance of a `DateTime` type.

Your first fix should be to change your parameter to be of type `DateTime` and not `string`. Otherwise a caller could pass `"HI THERE"` and your method/application would break, or worse push that value to a store and now your store is polluted with invalid value(s).

```
public void SomeMethod(DateTime daydate)
{
    var dateOnly = dayDate.Date;
}
```

Comment: So are you saying convert to a datetime first?

Comment: @user2320476 -  No, I am saying do not accept `string` as a parameter type when you are expecting a `DateTime` instance.

Comment: @user2320476 - ie. the caller should be forced to pass in an instance of `DateTime`, not string.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `dayDate` as a DateTime value instead of as a string. Then the format will work correctly.